# Enhanced for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Can you please convert this enhanced for loop to an ordinary one?

 `for (String sentence : notes.split(" *\."))` 

I'm fond of enhanced and normal for loop when the data type is an integer. But if it is a string, I'm confused. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is written in our book and I'm curious what is it's counterpart in the normal one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] sentences = notes.split(" *\.");
String sentence = null ;
int sentencesLength = sentences.length;

for(int i=0;i<sentencesLength;i++){
sentence = sentences[i];
//perform your task here

}
```

[Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/) has in-build feature for converting for-each to index based loop. Check it out.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much, Priyank Doshi! And to others also.

Comment: Best practice : add `n` (do not evaluate at each loop) : `for(int i=0, n=sentences.length;i<n;i++){ .. `

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [For-Each's Doc](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html).

```
String[] splitted_notes = notes.split(" *\. ");
for (int i=0; i < splitted_notes.length; i++) {
  // Code Here with splitted_notes[i]
}
```

Or a loop more similar to `for (String sentence : notes.split(" *\."))`

```
ArrayList<String> splitted_notes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(notes.split(";")));
for(Iterator<String> i = splitted_notes.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  String sentence = i.next();
  // Code Here with sentence
}
```

Comment: `sentence = splitted_notes[i++]` ? no need for it inside the loop if `i` isn't actually being used

Comment: you can pull the `i++` part into the third part of `for`: `...; sentence = ..., i++)`

Comment: instead of `sentence = splitted_notes[i], i++` you can always use `sentence = splitted_notes[i++]` :)

Comment: Basic `i` is being used. He just take each `splitted_notes`'s string. But your code is leaner!

Comment: Hmm.. Second though on the second suggestion: In the first iteration `sentence` is _not_ the first sentence but `""`. AND you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the last iteration.

Comment: using `i++` should increment `i` after it's been read for that operation as opposed to `++i` ... http://www.coderanch.com/t/5260/Cattle-Drive/vs

Comment: But, at first iteration, it still `""`

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] splitResult=notes.split(" *\.");
for (String sentence : splitResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary for loop -

```
String[] strArray = notes.split(" *\.");
String sentence = null;
  for(int i=0 ;i <strArray.length ; i++){
    sentence = strArray[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns you the `String[]`.

```
String[] array=notes.split(" *\.");
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {

    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like so:

```
String[] splitString = notes.split(" *\."));
for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++)
{
    //...
}
```

OR

```
for(String str : splitString)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] array = notes.split(" *\."));
String sentence;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
sentence = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the regex itself is a wrong one. The compiler will say

> illegal escape character

if

> "*\."

is the regex. So I am assuming that you are trying to split a string by have having

> . (a dot)

as a delimiter. In that case, the code would be like

```
String[] splittedNotes = notes.split("[.]");
for (int index = 0; index < splittedNotes.length; index++) {
   String sentence = splittedNotes[index];
}
```

On a polite note, you could have tried and got this by yourself. Cheers.